# Alternative for reading integer in C#

Tags: c#, input, type-conversion, inputstream, beginread

I know that for reading input by using `Convert.To` method,But is there any way to read other than this.

```
int k = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Doesn´t do this what you want?

Comment: You are supposed to use `Convert.ToInt32` actually. There's also `int.Parse`.

Comment: yeah it does but I  want is there any other method

Comment: why is that I want to use `Convert.ToInt32 `but it working fine with `To.Int16`

Comment: Well., if you write a number greater then 2^16 (more precise 2^16 - 1)the the former will evantually produce an error whilst `Convert.ToInt32` will work correctly.

Comment: How this isn't a duplicate question? I'm sure there are AT LEAST 20 similar.

Comment: Yeah I can accept that answer, but it always good to gain knowledge@SonerGönül

Answer (score 5):

To easiest method to read the input from a console application is `Console.ReadLine`. There are possible alternatives but they are more complex and reserved for special cases: See [Console.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

What is important however is the conversion to an integer number that shouldn't be done using `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse` but with [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int k = 0;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(Int32.TryParse(input, out k))
    Console.WriteLine("You have typed a valid integer: " + k);
else
    Console.WriteLine("This: " + input + " is not a valid integer");
```

The reason to use `Int32.TryParse` lies in the fact that you can check if the conversion to an integer is possible or not. The other methods instead raises an exception that you should handle complicating the flow of your code.

Comment: You have compilation time error because `k` variable is not initialized. In addition `Console.WriteLine("This: " + k + " is not a valid integer");` does not display wrond user's input

Comment: You are correct of course. Not thinking straight, in my defense I could say that I put the Console.WriteLine with the k value as an afterthought just to show the error

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own implementation for Console and use it everywhere you want:

```
public static class MyConsole
{
    public static int ReadInt()
    {
        int k = 0;
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(val, out k))
            Console.WriteLine("You have typed a valid integer: " + k);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("This: " + val + " is not a valid integer");
        return k;
    }

    public static double ReadDouble()
    {
        double k = 0;
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Double.TryParse(val, out k))
            Console.WriteLine("You have typed a valid double: " + k);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("This: " + val + " is not a valid double");
        return k;
    }
    public static bool ReadBool()
    {
        bool k = false;
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Boolean.TryParse(val, out k))
            Console.WriteLine("You have typed a valid bool: " + k);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("This: " + val + " is not a valid bool");
        return k;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int s = MyConsole.ReadInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: is this like a user defined function

Comment: These are just functions defined by user )

Answer (score 1):

you can use `int.TryParse`

see example

```
var item = Console.ReadLine();
int input;
if (int.TryParse(item, out input))
{
    // here you got item as int in input variable.
    // do your stuff.
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Entered value is invalid");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative and best [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can follow:

```
int k;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k))
   {
      //Do your stuff here
   }
else 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of integers:

1.) [Short Integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) : 16bit number (-32768 to 32767). In c# you can declare a short integer variable as `short` or `Int16`.

2.) ["Normal" Integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx): 32bit number (-2147483648 to 2147483647). Declare a integer with the keywords `int` or `Int32`.

3.) [Long Integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx): 64bit number (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807). Declare a long integer with `long` or `Int64`.

The difference is the range of numbers you can use.
You can convert them by using `Convert.To`, `Parse` or `TryParse`.